# React Native FlatList not rendering items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

```
<Query
      query={FETCH_EVENTS}>
      {
        ({data, error, loading }) => {
          if (loading) return null;
          if (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return <Text>An error occured</Text>;
          }
          if (!data.allEvents) return null;
          return(
            <FlatList
              style={{flex: 1}}
              data={data.allEvents}
              renderItem={({ item }) => {
                <EventCard
                  event={item}
                  key={item.id}
                  latitude={latitude}
                  longitude={longitude}
                  />
              }}
              keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            />
          )
        }
      }
    </Query>
```

The above code suddenly stopped working for no apparent reason, I can't figure out why the FlatList is no longer rendering items.

When I replace the FlatList by the following component directly, it works and renders so the issue should not be related to the component but to the FlatList.

```
return(
            <EventCard
              event={data.allEvents[0]}
              key={data.allEvents[0].id}
              latitude={latitude}
              longitude={longitude}/>
          )
```

Comment: please post the error log.

Comment: there are no error log, just nothing gets rendered. @bk7

Comment: check my answer @Hugo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Forgot to return statement in **renderItem**

try this

```
               <FlatList
                  style={{flex: 1}}
                  data={data.allEvents}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => {
                 return(
                    <EventCard
                      event={item}
                      key={item.id}
                      latitude={latitude}
                      longitude={longitude}
                      />);
                  }}
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
```

or

```
        <FlatList
                  style={{flex: 1}}
                  data={data.allEvents}
                  renderItem={({ item }) => 

                    <EventCard
                      event={item}
                      key={item.id}
                      latitude={latitude}
                      longitude={longitude}
                      />
                  }
                  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
```

both of the above solutions should work

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning the EventCard

```
renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <EventCard
              event={item}
              key={item.id}
              latitude={latitude}
              longitude={longitude}
              />
 )}
```

Instead of

```
renderItem={({ item }) => {
            <EventCard
              event={item}
              key={item.id}
              latitude={latitude}
              longitude={longitude}
              />
  }}
```